# match parts of text

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need idea about logic which will match repeated character sets comparing two strings.

`Car is blue and new` vs `Car is blue and old`, would find 16 matches
`Car is , blue` vs `Car is blue color` would find `Car is` match and  `blue`

So basically I need to find percentually how much repeating characters are the same in two strings, SQL Server or C#, preferably SQL server.

I don't expect someone to write me code, but any idea, link or something like that would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Little idea here, you could get a list of all the words in one string, and then check if they exist in the other string:

```
string baseStringOne = "Car is blue and new", baseStringTwo = "Car is blue and old"; 
string[] subs = baseStringOne.Split(' '); 
foreach (string sub in subs)
{
  if (baseStringTwo.Contains(sub))
  {
     //Substring found!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find these relevant:
[The diff algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm)
[An implementation for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13326/An-O-ND-Difference-Algorithm-for-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can get distinct characters by :

```
public static string Common(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return new string((s1.Intersect(s2)).ToArray());
    }
```